# The mean of a geometric random variable

Tags: random-variables, self-learning

The mean of a geometric random variable is

$$
\frac{1-p}{p}
$$

What would be the mean of *x* for this density function?

$$
f_{x}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{k} \delta (x-k)
$$
I got confused with the delta function!

Comment: That density function _is_ the geometric random variable, isn't it?  (Assuming we're using the count-the-number-of-failures option instead of count-the-number-of-attempts.)  So I guess you've already got the mean.

Comment: This is a density function of a geometric random variable.

Comment: So then we're done here?  What was your question?

Comment: What would be the answer if the delta function is not exist? Does the delta function affect the answer if it's not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirac delta function is zero everywhere except when its argument is zero, and integrates to become a one.  Since the support of the function $f$ is a discrete set (all the nonnegative integers), integrating over it (e.g. finding the mean using $\int_{\Bbb R}xf(x)\,dx$) is the same as doing a summation over that discrete set.  To pick $k=4$ at random,
$$\int_{\Bbb R} xp(1-p)^4\delta(x-4)\,dx = 4p(1-p)^4,$$
since the only value of $x$ that matters is $x=4$, because that's where the delta function has support, and we substitute that value in.  Integrating a sum is the sum of the integrals, so the integral just becomes the traditional discrete formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp(1-p)^k.$$

Comment: I meant to add, since you asked, that if the delta function wasn't there the function $f(x)$ would just be constant everywhere, and so wouldn't be an actual pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\delta(x-k)\,\mathrm{d}x=k
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac1{1-x}\\
&=\frac1{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#00A000}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p(1-p)^k\color{#00A000}{\delta(x-k)\,\mathrm{d}x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \color{#00A000}{k}p(1-p)^k\\
&=p(1-p)\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\color{#C00000}{(1-p)}^{k-1}\\
&=p(1-p)\frac1{(1-\color{#C00000}{(1-p)})^2}\\
&=\frac{1-p}{p}
\end{align}
$$

---

We can use
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\frac1{1-x}\\
&=\frac2{(1-x)^3}
\end{align}
$$
to get the variance,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left((X-\mathrm{E}(X))^2\right)
&=\mathrm{E}\left(X^2\right)-2\mathrm{E}(X)\mathrm{E}(X)+\mathrm{E}(X)^2\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(X^2\right)-\mathrm{E}(X)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2p(1-p)^k-\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)p(1-p)^k+\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp(1-p)^k-\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2\\
&=p(1-p)^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\color{#C00000}{(1-p)}^{k-2}+\frac{1-p}{p}-\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2\\
&=p(1-p)^2\frac2{\left(1-\color{#C00000}{(1-p)}\right)^3}+\frac{1-p}{p}-\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1-p}{p^2}
\end{align}
$$

---

We can use
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)(k-2)x^{k-2}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}x^3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}x^3}\frac1{1-x}\\
&=\frac6{(1-x)^4}
\end{align}
$$
to get the third moment,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left((X-\mathrm{E}(X))^3\right)
&=\mathrm{E}\left(X^3\right)-3\mathrm{E}\left(X^2\right)\mathrm{E}(X)+3\mathrm{E}(X)\mathrm{E}(X)^2-\mathrm{E}(X)^3\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(X^3\right)-\mathrm{E}(X)^3-3\mathrm{E}(X)\mathrm{Var}(X)
\end{align}
$$
First compute
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(X^3\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^3p(1-p)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k(k-1)(k-2)+\color{#00A000}{3k(k-1)}+\color{#0000FF}{k})p(1-p)^k\\
&=p(1-p)^3\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)(k-2)\color{#C00000}{(1-p)}^{k-3}+\color{#00A000}{6\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2}+\color{#0000FF}{\frac{1-p}{p}}\\
&=p(1-p)^3\frac6{(1-\color{#C00000}{(1-p)})^4}+6\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2+\frac{1-p}{p}\\
&=6\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^3+6\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2+\frac{1-p}{p}
\end{align}
$$
Putting the last two equations together, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left((X-\mathrm{E}(X))^3\right)
&=6\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^3+6\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^2+\frac{1-p}{p}\\
&-\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^3\\
&-3\frac{1-p}{p}\frac{1-p}{p^2}\\
&=\frac{(2-p)(1-p)}{p^3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you robjohn! Can you also help me how we can find the third moment?

Comment: Well, if we say "third moment", it means $ E(X^{3}) $, doesn't?